# JavaScript Object parameters changing when reading them over network

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason that I cannot seem to wrap my brain around, whenever I send an `Object` over the network, its parameters change from when I send the `Object` over the network from the server to when I read it back on the client.

**Here's the scenario:**

I'm testing an API to delete your user account from the database. You send over your `authToken` and `username` parameters in a specially formatted `Object`, the server queries the database, and if found, your user account is deleted. When everything works perfectly, your account, the server sends this string back to you:

```
{ header: { type: 'success' }, body: {} }
```

That's known as a plain `SuccessEnvelope`. However, when I read the returned string from the server, I get this:

```
{ header: { type: 'error' }, body: {} }
```

Now, it seems that the `type` parameter is being changed somewhere, but I have no idea where! Below you'll find the relevant code which handles all of these requests:

**server.js**

```
server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.on("data", function(data) {
    try {
      // Accept Envelope from client
      var input = new Envelope(data.toString());
      if (input.verify()) { // Make sure client Envelope has correct data
        switch (input.header.type) { // Route commands based on Envelope "type"
        case "user":
          userHandler.parseEnvelope(input, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
              socket.write(errors.parseError(err).toString());
            } else {
              socket.write(res.toString());
            }
          });
          break;
        default:
          socket.write(new Envelope().toString());
          break;
        }
      } else {
        socket.write(errors.parseError(
          new errors.MissingHeaderDataError()).toString());
      }
    } catch (err) {
      socket.write(errors.parseError(err).toString());
    }
  });
});
```

**user-handler.js**

```
// removing some of the unnecessary stuff
case "delete":
  // Make sure user provided all necessary information.
  if (!header.token || !body.username) {
    return callback(new errors.MissingEnvelopeDataError("Missing the 'token' and/or
      'username' parameter(s) in header and/or body, respectively"));
  } else {
    // Delete the user's account. So sad to see them go... :'(
    User.findOne({"token": header.token, "username": body.username}, "+token +_id",
      function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      } else {
        user.remove(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return callback(err);
          } else {
            // Everything went according to plan. Return a SuccessEnvelope to the user.
            callback(new SuccessEnvelope());
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  break;
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong? Any help would be fantastic. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** It's probably also a good idea to include my test cases...

```
deleteUser = {
  "header": {
    "type": "user",
    "method": "delete",
    "token": ""
  },
  "body": {
    "username": ""
  }
}

describe("Delete user", function() {
  it("should return a MissingEnvelopeDataError when deleting a user without a token or
      username", function(done) {
    connection.write(JSON.stringify(deleteUser));
    connection.on("data", function(res) {
      res = JSON.parse(res.toString());
      res.header.should.have.property("type", "error");
      res.header.should.have.property("errorType", "MissingEnvelopeDataError");
      done();
    });
  });
  it("should return a SuccessEnvelope when deleting a user", function(done) {
    deleteUser.header.token = user.token;
    deleteUser.body.username = user.username;
    connection.write(JSON.stringify(deleteUser));
    connection.on("data", function(res) {
      res = JSON.parse(res.toString());
      console.dir(res);

      res.header.should.have.property("type", "success");
      // res.body.should.be.empty
      (function() {
        if (Object.keys(res.body).length == 0) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      })();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

The `user` variable you see here is just a simple object, which stores all of the user info.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you've quoted. How do I know? Because **something** has to set `type: 'error'` and the only place the word `error` appears in your question is in your example invalid response, nowhere in the code.

Comment: I added the test cases that I'm using for this. This **should** be the only code that handles any of this.

Comment: @ZachDziura But it's not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I'm an idiot and don't follow my own API.

The `callback` function that's being passed takes two parameters: `err` and `response`. I was forgetting to pass `null` as my error, so the code was doing exactly what it should have been doing. DOH! Thanks for the responses, everyone!